Change geom value of a database layer
I have a view that matches my table. On it I have an Update trigger that normally allows me to update attributes such as geometry. But I can't update the geometry. I tried several thing but it didn't work.
with edit(table_view):
       table_view.updateFeature(feature) # Change attributes and geometry becomes null


table_view.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(geom) #geom doesn't change
table_view.dataProvider().changeFeatures(hgt_change, hgt_geom_change) # attr and geom doesn't change


There’s not enough information in your question to help you. What is the value of feature? What are the values of geom, hgt_change, and hgt_geom_change? updateFeature expects the feature to be fully populated with attributes and geometry, and most importantly, an id, so qgis knows which feature to update. changeGeometryValues expects a mapping, not a single QgsGeometry instance. Without knowing what you are passing to these functions, it’s not possible to guess what might be going on.

I've solved my problem, I simply hadn't specified in my Data source that the table had a geometry of
self.uri.setDataSource('schema', "table_name", 'geom', None, "pk")
